# Delta imports in Oracle ATG commerce

Tags: atg, commerce

Is there an Out Of the Box way to import daily product/sku delta data into ATG CA for subsequent deployment into production target?  How is this done normally as this would be a requirement in every project.

I know about the repository loader scripts but not sure if that fits the bill as I only want deltas

Comment: Every ATG project that I've worked on has done this in a different programmatic way. We generally use repository loader to get the initial data in but from then on use custom written dataloaders for processing daily feeds.

Comment: @radimpe, For processing daily feeds, I assume the process would be to import the feed into a project into ATG CA & then publish it. Is there not a consistent (ideally an out of the box way) of importing this into a project & publishing it. Why would each have a diff way?

Comment: On the projects I've worked, the main difference has been about where we consume the data that gets pumped into the projects. The other thing to consider is whether you want to version your data. For example we tend to not version our inventory data (so we actually don't load it via CA) but we do version our product data.

Comment: @radimpe, sorry to persist on this :-) Speaking specifically about item data (products, skus) when it is versioned. Did you write custom code to import into CA or did you use something like startSQLRepositoty ? Would you have a view on the pros & cons of the custom approach vs using something like a startSQLrepository.

Comment: Which version of ATG are you using? If you do use `startSQLRepository` to load your data that will only get it into a project (provided you did that correct). You still need to publish the project. By doing this with custom code and writing your own workflow (.wdl file) you can do all of it in one job. I would do it with some custom code again. Generally `startSQLRepository` has been useful in getting development environments setup with an initial load but custom code is used to do ongoing dataload tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As of ATG 10.2.0.2, No.  APIs exist for the programmatic creation of projects and querying current data; however custom code needs to be written to make this work.